# Unity not showing full text

Tags: unity

This is simple issue, I'm trying to put in text, but it keeps cutting off, I found nothing in it's settings for text limited

[Screenshot http://puu.sh/jbx9B/d6ab34678f.png](http://puu.sh/jbx9B/d6ab34678f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical Overflow is set to Truncate. In other words, the text cuts off when it reaches the boundaries of the text element. Note the Height 30 above? That's the vertical boundary; you want that to be taller. You probably also want to make the element wider, so that it wraps at the edge of the window instead of in the middle.